# Submit form on layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in mvc. I like to submit a form with a button from the layout page. Need to pass somehow a model as well to the controller of the view. Any hints or ideas?

```
@if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Benutzername">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Login"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Registrieren" />
</form>
}
else {
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Logout">
    </form>
}
```

---

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Benutzername")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Kennwort")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Speichern?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Benutzername")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "&quote{0}&quote muss mindestens {2} Zeichen lang sein.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Kennwort")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Kennwort bestätigen")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Das Kennwort entspricht nicht dem Bestätigungskennwort.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You'll need an `action` attribute on the `form` element in order for those forms to be posted. Point that at a controller/action of your choice and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `name` of each `input` tag bind into the properties of your `Model` class, so, just add the `name` attribute within the property name you want bind, for sample:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" placeholder="Benutzername">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Passwort">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Login"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Registrieren" />
</form>
```

### Tips

I would recommend you change this code to a `PartialView` instead keep on the `Layout` page. It is useful because you can type your `PartialView` with your model and generate the input tags using `Html` helper like `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, ...)`, for sample. There are a lot of [Html Helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) can help you like [Html.BeginForm() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx)  All I've said here, it is a good pratice, but your code will run fine because these good pratices generated a code like yours.

Comment: Now after any postback the login controller gets hitten. Trying a PartialView.

Answer (score 1):

The model for your layout must be the same as the model for your page.  As such, this is not particularly practical, unless you want to use a base model for everything which is not good practice.

A better approach is to use an `Html.Action()` and use a separate controller action for your login form, then it can have its own model and its own execution context.

Answer (score 1):

How about a couple of PartialViews?  Here is a rough/general example:

```
public class Login {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Register : Login {
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Partial for Login:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Partial for Register:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Reference the partial's in your layout (or any other view):

```
@Html.Partial("LoginPartial")
@Html.Partial("RegisterPartial")
```